# Undo Wordpress Mistake

Tags: wordpress, undo

How can I undo some mistakes in my Wordpress Webpage when I imported unwanted widgets, menus, etc... I am getting so frustrated I was ready to delete everything and start anew. I wish I could revert to a previous session but I can't find an option for that on the Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a plugin like updraftplus this will allow you to take backups of the website if your hosting does not offer that. WordPress does not natively give you a revert feature the only other work around is to edit the files directly in the database to see when certain areas where added via a tool like MySQL or PHPMyAdmin

without a backup here you are in a bit of a difficult situation.